# Adding Model Only Tool (Select Data) to model in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, arcgis-10.5

I know the Select Data tool exists because of its documentation here:

http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/modelbuilder-toolbox/select-data.htm

However, when I search for the tool in ArcGIS Desktop 10.5 it does not appear. In fact, I can't find where any Model Only Tools are located.

Is there some trick to finding these like turning them on or downloading them separately?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer hidden away here:

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/modelbuilder/accessing-model-only-tools.htm

> Click **Insert > Model Only Tools** and choose the tool you want to add.
>
> - Alternatively, right-click anywhere in the model and click **Model Only Tools**, then choose the tool you want to add.